# Can I add metadata (new fields) with respect to apexClass, apexPage, AuraDefinitionBundle

Tags: version-control

Is it possible to add new fields to "code" objects like apexClass, apexPage, auraDefinitionBundle?

Basically, trying to add legacy code to version control while continuing to use sandboxes - moving code into appropriate project directories, and I want to record a link to source code management repo that each particular file is stored in.

If it isn't possible to add a field to a code object that records this info, is there any where else that would make salesforce sense to store this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot extra fields on Apex Classes, Pages and LWC/Aura.

But what you can do is , specify these files as part of independent project packages using Salesforce DX Unlocked packages.

**Src:**

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/06/working-with-modular-development-and-unlocked-packages-part-1.html

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/06/working-with-modular-development-and-unlocked-packages-part-3.html

Comment: I don't feel like salesforce dx is useful for me - perhaps designed for larger orgs with large teams of developers? It seems like a large investment of time to get my head around the workflow for little benefit, since I don't have a problem with developing in sandbox - the only problem I'm trying to solve is a more clearly organised code base, a clear history of code change rather than just deployments, and ease of sharing code between sandboxes. Last time I tried salesforce dx I think it ended up pulling in 95% of the org when I just wanted to change a visualforce controller.